# Github: How would I move one repository into another preserving my commit history?

Tags: git, github

Newbie here
Suppose I have a repository AAA

```
AAA
 |- folder1(contains files)
 |- folder2(contains files)
```

I wish to transfer the contents of repository AAA into the empty repository BBB. How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to just copy the file structure from a particular branch, or do you really want a complete carbon copy of a repository?

Comment: I have no branches. A carbon copy please

Comment: Are both repositories on your computer, or remote?

Comment: They are Remotes I think

Comment: Why don’t you clone AAA as BBB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just copy folder AAA as BBB (including the .git directory present inside AAA)